# php extract standalone numbers from a line

Tags: php, string, numbers, line, extract

I want to extract standalone numbers from this line

```
4000123456789000/01/20/202/sssss/500 address/400 city/366
```

to have this result

```
4000123456789000/01/20/202/366
```

the problem that the codes gives me this result

```
4000123456789000/01/20/202/500/400/366
```

I don't want the numbers which have the text along with it and I don't want to remove the delimiter

Comment: but `366` has a text `city`

Comment: @u_mulder city has the number 400 not 366 , it's another value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using `preg_match_all` and `str_replace` functions (to extract standalone numbers):

```
$str = "4000123456789000/01/20/202/sssss/500 address/400 city/366";

preg_match_all("/\/?\d+?(\/|$)/i", $str, $matches);
$numbers_string = str_replace("//", "/", implode("", $matches[0]));

print_r($numbers_string);
```

The output:

```
4000123456789000/01/20/202/366
```

Answer (score 0):

You can break it up into array and then extract the respective keys.

```
 $str   =  '4000123456789000/01/20/202/sssss/500 address/400 city/366';

 $array = explode("/", $str);

 $formatted_array = array($array[0], $array[1], $array[2],  $array[3],end($array));

 echo implode("/", $formatted_array);
```